With ridge regression, weights can approach 0 for large values of lambda but will never equal 0 (unlike Lasso). Why?
I've been trying to figure out why Ridge regression has weights approach 0 for large values of lambda but they are never equal to 0, unlike Lasso and Simple Linear Regression.
According to this website: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/ridge-lasso-regression-python-complete-tutorial/
They illustrate the concept using gradient descent. For Ridge, they characterise the weight update as:
$w_j^{t + 1} = (1 - 2*\lambda*\alpha)w_j^t + 2*\alpha \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij}\{y_i - \sum_{k=0}^M w_k * x_{i,k}\}$
The article claims that because we're reducing $w_j^t$ by a factor of $(1 - 2*\lambda*\alpha)$, we cannot get 0 but can only get smaller values approaching 0 assuming $\lambda, \alpha > 0$. However, what if $2 * \lambda * \alpha = 1$? There's no explanation for this case.
So does anyone know the real reason why Ridge approaches 0 but never equals 0 for weights but LASSO does?

I would suggest you read from: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)
It provides geometric, Bayesian and other interpretations for why LASSO is able to achieve 0 coefficients while ridge is not.
But in practicality alot of the times LASSO coefficients also tend to be very close to zero and not actually zero like in Ridge.
